# nodejs express and using https

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, ssl, https

I'm looking to implement a running express server using https, powering an AngularJS application.  Currently I have the majority of the application running just on http, but would like to switch over.  This isn't a publicly available application.  Am I ok to simply use self-signed certificates to implement this in our production environment?  Or should I be going through a trusted certificate authority even for internal use?

Using OpenSSL seems pretty simple to generate the key and pem files... but I feel dumb when it comes to acquiring something through a trusted authority.  If it's recommended that I DO in fact use a trusted CA, and not self-signed, could someone point me in the right direction on where to go for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is "it depends".

You can certainly use self-signed certs, but you will have to manually make sure that all your endpoints are configured to trust your self-signed certs.  This is what a trusted certificate authority is used for.  The browser has pre-built trust for certificates issues by various public certificate authorities and, in turn, they agree to follow certain procedures related to issuing their certificates.  If you go through that process, then browsers will automatically recognized and trust https connections using your certificates (assuming everything is as expected with the connection).  If you don't go through that process, then you have to manually tell each endpoint that is going to access your application to trust your certificates.  For closed applications with a small number of controlled endpoints, this is very feasible.  For open applications or applications with a wide variety of endpoints (random browsers, phones, etc...), this is difficult.

And, you do not want to "teach" your user base to either ignore security/certificate warnings or to blindly trust things that the browser tells them might be insecure so you want to not leave this to your users - you want to pre-configure the endpoints to trust your new self-signed certs.

---

To give you an example, there are home security camera systems that have web access.  If the only ways you need to do web access are from 2 or 3 different browsers, it's not really a problem to use a self-signed cert and configure those 3 browsers to trust it.

But, if you had some web application that many different people would access, then it wouldn't really be practical to manage the certificate trust on a rotating set of browsers and it would just be a lot less complicated and a lot more likely to be secure to use a trusted CA.

Comment: @dvsoukup - Did this answer your question?

Comment: Hey, it did!  Thanks a bunch.  Got up and running at work with a self-signed cert and have a path forward for using an actual verified cert.  Should work well for the users.   Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer using CA trusted certificates over self-signed certificates for production environments (or even developer environments) since you need to trust/add exceptions or overwrite programatic SSL checks when you are using self-signed certificates.

If you decide to use CA trusted certificates, I recommend looking into [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) + [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). It is a trusted CA and supports most of the famous servers. It is also free and really easy to use. The only downside is that you need to renew the certificate every 3 months. This too can be automated depending on your platform/server.